# TRIGGER that calculates the STATUS of a student in a table

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need to construct a Trigger so that every time a new row is inserted into the SUBJECT table with the data (STDID, SUBJID, SEMESTER / YEAR, GRADE, FREQ), the value of the STATUS field is calculated and entered automatically. The approval rules are in the RULES table, whose schema is below. This table has only one row, but brings the facility of being able to be changed dynamically. For example, in the case of the my university, it would have a line with the data  5.0(minimum grade) and 75% (minimum frequencie), but in another University could be 7.0 and 80%.
Table RULES (minGRADE, minFREQ)

I have two tables:

SUBJECT

```
STDID   SUBJID   SEMESTER_YEAR  GRADE    FREQ   STATUS
1111    2         2/2018          6       75    ok
1111    13        2/2018          7       100   ok
1111    4         1/2018          5       90    ok
1111    7         1/2018          10      95    ok
1111    9         2/2018          8       75    ok
1122    2         2/2017          3       75    no
1122    13        2/2017          5       100   ok
1122    4         1/2017          5       90    ok
1122    7         1/2017          10      95    ok
1122    9         2/2017          8       75    ok
1113    2         2/2018          6       75    ok
1113    13        2/2018          7       100   ok
1113    4         1/2018          5       90    ok
1113    7         1/2018          4       95    no
1113    9         2/2018          8       75    ok
1132    2         2/2018          3       75    no
1132    13        2/2018          7       100   ok
1132    4         1/2018          5       90    ok
1132    7         1/2018          4       95    no
1132    9         2/2018          8       75    ok
```

And the other: STUDENT

```
            STDID     NAME      DATA_NASC
            1111    gabriel     12-APR-70
            1112    pedro       12-JUN-70
            1113    lucas       12-MAR-70
            1114    mariana     12-FEB-70
            1115    klemer      12-SEP-70
            1116    jose        12-DEC-70
            1117    vitor       12-NOV-70
            1118    artur       12-APR-70
            1119    bia         12-NOV-70
            1120    julia       12-MAR-70
            1121    rafaela     12-JAN-70
            1122    augusto     12-FEB-70
            1123    eneas       12-JUL-70
            1124    zezinho     12-APR-70
            1125    hugo        12-APR-70
            1126    matheus     12-APR-70
            1127    diana       12-APR-70
            1128    andre       12-APR-70
            1129    reco        12-APR-70
```

I'm stuck on how to create this trigger to calculate automatically

Answer (score 1):

For obtaining the STATUS values, consider using a VIEW (rather than a trigger).  You have mentioned a RULES table (containing minGRADE etc).  If you are using Oracle 12c (or newer), you could use a LATERAL JOIN for "calculating" the values of the STATUS column on the fly.

**RULES table**

```
create table rules ( univid, mingrade, minfreq )
as
select 1, 5, 75 from dual ;
```

Using the definition and data of your SUBJECT table, we can use this query to get the required results (notice: no trigger).  We fetch the MINGRADE and MINFREQ from the RULES table, and use these values (via LATERAL JOIN) in the main query's CASE.

```
select S.*
, case
    when grade >= mingrade and freq >= minfreq then 'ok'
    else 'not ok'
  end as status
from subject S, lateral ( 
  select mingrade, minfreq from rules where univid = 1
);


-- result
     STDID     SUBJID SEMEST      GRADE       FREQ STATUS
---------- ---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ------
      1111          2 2/2018          6         75 ok    
      1111         13 2/2018          7        100 ok    
      1111          4 1/2018          5         90 ok    
      1111          7 1/2018         10         95 ok    
      1111          9 2/2018          8         75 ok    
      1122          2 2/2017          3         75 not ok
      1122         13 2/2017          5        100 ok    
      1122          4 1/2017          5         90 ok    
      1122          7 1/2017         10         95 ok    
      1122          9 2/2017          8         75 ok    
      1113          2 2/2018          6         75 ok    
      1113         13 2/2018          7        100 ok    
      1113          4 1/2018          5         90 ok    
      1113          7 1/2018          4         95 not ok
      1113          9 2/2018          8         75 ok    
      1132          2 2/2018          3         75 not ok
      1132         13 2/2018          7        100 ok    
      1132          4 1/2018          5         90 ok    
      1132          7 1/2018          4         95 not ok
      1132          9 2/2018          8         75 ok    

20 rows selected.
```

We assume here that all students are matriculated at University 1 - see [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95acff417054302e88db74185d84d1ab).

If you are dealing with several rules (for several universities),  you can still use this approach - without coding a trigger.  In the example below, we {1} create an enrolments table, which contains STUDENT-UNIVERSITY mappings.  For simplicity, we just "enrol" students with even studentids into uni 1, students with odd studentids go into uni 2. {2} We add a rule for uni 2 to the RULES table.

```
-- ENROLMENTS table
create table enrolments( studentid, universityid )
as
select
  stdid, mod( stdid, 2 ) + 1
from subject ;

-- add a RULE
insert into rules ( univid, mingrade, minfreq ) values ( 2, 7, 80 ) ;

-- the RULES table now contains ...
SQL> select * from rules ;

    UNIVID   MINGRADE    MINFREQ
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5         75
         2          7         80
```

This following query will give us the STATUS values according to the RULES defined for uni 1 and uni 2, respectively. (If there are more universities/rules, just add enrolments and rules.  No triggers.)

**Query**

```
select unique
  S.*
, case
    when grade >= mingrade and freq >= minfreq then 'ok'
    else 'not ok'
  end as status
, R.univid   as "R.uni"        -- output: the universityid
, R.mingrade as "R.mingrade"   -- and the rules
, R.minfreq  as "R.minfreq"    -- for both universities - just for "illustration"
from subject S
, lateral(
  select universityid from enrolments where S.stdid = studentid
) E 
join rules R on E.universityid = R.univid
;
```

**Result**

```
STDID  SUBJID  SEMESTER_YEAR  GRADE  FREQ  STATUS  R.uni  R.mingrade  R.minfreq  
1122   13      2/2017         5      100   ok      1      5           75         
1122   2       2/2017         3      75    not ok  1      5           75         
1113   9       2/2018         8      75    not ok  2      7           80         
1132   9       2/2018         8      75    ok      1      5           75         
1113   4       1/2018         5      90    not ok  2      7           80         
1113   13      2/2018         7      100   ok      2      7           80         
1132   7       1/2018         4      95    not ok  1      5           75         
1132   4       1/2018         5      90    ok      1      5           75         
1132   2       2/2018         3      75    not ok  1      5           75         
1111   2       2/2018         6      75    not ok  2      7           80         
1122   7       1/2017         10     95    ok      1      5           75         
1113   7       1/2018         4      95    not ok  2      7           80         
1111   4       1/2018         5      90    not ok  2      7           80         
1111   7       1/2018         10     95    ok      2      7           80         
1111   13      2/2018         7      100   ok      2      7           80         
1122   9       2/2017         8      75    ok      1      5           75         
1111   9       2/2018         8      75    not ok  2      7           80         
1132   13      2/2018         7      100   ok      1      5           75         
1113   2       2/2018         6      75    not ok  2      7           80         
1122   4       1/2017         5      90    ok      1      5           75         


20 rows selected.
```

[DBfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5119928df55a9e32f2fb8efcaf642027).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to handle incoming record values before they're written. This lets you set `SUBJECT.STATUS` based on incoming `SUBJECT` column values.

Triggers use the `:NEW` alias to represent the column values that are about to be written with the `INSERT` statement. You can query or change the incoming values. This trigger does both: it queries grade and frequency, and it changes status.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SUBJECT_STATUS
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON SUBJECT
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  stat SUBJECT.STATUS%TYPE;
  minGrade RULES.MINIMUM_GRADE%TYPE;
  minFreq RULE.MINIMUM_FREQ%TYPE;

BEGIN

  -- Read minimum grade and frequency into variables
  SELECT MINIMUM_GRADE, MINIMUM_FREQ
    INTO minGrade, minFreq
    FROM RULES;

  IF :NEW.GRADE >= minGrade AND :NEW.FREQ >= minFreq THEN
    -- If the student achieves minimum grade and frequency then status is "ok"
    :NEW.STATUS := 'ok';
  ELSE
    -- If not then status is "no"
    :NEW.STATUS := 'no';
  END IF;

END;
```

Notes:

- This code assumes that your `RULES` table has the columns `MINIMUM_GRADE` and `MINIMUM_FREQ` for the minimum grade and frequency, respectively. If your actual column names are different then use those instead.
- The code also uses the Oracle `%TYPE` attribute to define the variable type based on the underlying column type. So if the `SUBJECT.STATUS` column is `VARCHAR2(2)` then the `stat` variable will be `VARCHAR2(2)`. If it's `CHAR(2)` then `stat` will be `CHAR(2)`. If it's `VARCHAR2(500)` then `stat` will be `VARCHAR2(500)`. And so on.
- I haven't explained the `CREATE TRIGGER` declaration at the top. If you have any questions about it please leave a note and I'll be happy to explain.